# Обработка правил брандмауэра Windows с помощью javascript и regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь структурировать результат консольной команды `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule dir=in name=all profile=private` с помощью js
Примерно вот так оно выглядит:

```
Имя правила:                          VMware Authd Service (private)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Включен:                              Да
Направление:                          Вход
Profiles:                             Частный
Группировка:
LocalIP:                              Любой
Удаленный IP-адрес:                   LocalSubnet
Протокол:                             Любой
Обход узлов:                          Да
Действие:                             Разрешить

Имя правила:                          Сервер потоковой передачи на устройство (потоковая передача, RTSP - входящий)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Включен:                              Да
Направление:                          Вход
Profiles:                             Частный
Группировка:                          Функция "Передать на устройство"
LocalIP:                              Любой
Удаленный IP-адрес:                   LocalSubnet
Протокол:                             TCP
Локальный порт:                       23554,23555,23556
Удаленный порт:                       Любой
Обход узлов:                          Нет
Действие:                             Разрешить
```

Хотел разделить их регулярным выражением и потом split'ом
Однако, написать такую регулярку не получилось
Примерно так должно выглядеть на выходе:

Совпадение 1:

```
Имя правила:                          VMware Authd Service (private)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Включен:                              Да
Направление:                          Вход
Profiles:                             Частный
Группировка:
LocalIP:                              Любой
Удаленный IP-адрес:                   LocalSubnet
Протокол:                             Любой
Обход узлов:                          Да
Действие:                             Разрешить
```

Совпадение 2:

```
Имя правила:                          Сервер потоковой передачи на устройство (потоковая передача, RTSP - входящий)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Включен:                              Да
Направление:                          Вход
Profiles:                             Частный
Группировка:                          Функция "Передать на устройство"
LocalIP:                              Любой
Удаленный IP-адрес:                   LocalSubnet
Протокол:                             TCP
Локальный порт:                       23554,23555,23556
Удаленный порт:                       Любой
Обход узлов:                          Нет
Действие:                             Разрешить
```

В общем, нужна помощь с регуляркой для этой задачки

Comment: Как вариант попробовать сплитом разбить так: `\s(?=^.*?$\s+^-+$)`

Comment: Разделяйте на строки, перебирайте строки, проверяя наличие строки с "Имя правила:", эту строку и следующие добавляйте в массив, если встретите еще строку с "Имя правила:", то её и те что после нее в новый массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм:

- Разделение текста на строки. Тут удобно использовать `split` с регулярным выражением `\r?\n` (строки заканчиваются на `\r\n` или на `\n`)
- Перебор строк. Можно циклом, можно функцией
- Проверка наличия строки с `"Имя правила:"`
- Эту строку и следующие добавляйте в под массив `rule`

В результате получите массив из массивов

Пример:

```js
let text = `\
Имя правила:                          VMware Authd Service (private)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Включен:                              Да
Направление:                          Вход
Profiles:                             Частный
Группировка:
LocalIP:                              Любой
Удаленный IP-адрес:                   LocalSubnet
Протокол:                             Любой
Обход узлов:                          Да
Действие:                             Разрешить

Имя правила:                          Сервер потоковой передачи на устройство (потоковая передача, RTSP - входящий)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Включен:                              Да
Направление:                          Вход
Profiles:                             Частный
Группировка:                          Функция "Передать на устройство"
LocalIP:                              Любой
Удаленный IP-адрес:                   LocalSubnet
Протокол:                             TCP
Локальный порт:                       23554,23555,23556
Удаленный порт:                       Любой
Обход узлов:                          Нет
Действие:                             Разрешить
`;
let lines = text.split(/\r?\n/);
let rules = [];
let rule = null;
for (let line of lines) {
    if (line.includes('Имя правила:')) {
        rule = [];
        rules.push(rule);
    }
    if (rule != null) {
        rule.push(line);
    }
}

console.log(rules);
```